# How to make Spring security to redirect user to the original requested page after successfully authenticated by the CAS server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, cas

I have a spring boot RESTFul web application, which uses [CAS](https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/planning/Architecture.html) server for Enterprise Single Sign-On. If a user, who is not logged-in, tries to access a secure page, that user is redirected to the CAS server for authentication. On successful authentication, the user is redirected to the home page of spring boot RESTFul web application - not the secured page, the user tries to access. How can we directly redirect the user to the secure page, which the user wants to access after successful login?

The spring-security-cas-client is used to implement CAS authentication. An AuthenticationSuccessHandler is implemented to set UseReferer true. The spring security config class is as follows:

```
package com.example.app

import java.util.Arrays;
import org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties;
import org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter;    
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
private SingleSignOutFilter singleSignOutFilter;
private LogoutFilter logoutFilter;

@Autowired
public SecurityConfig(CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider, 
AuthenticationEntryPoint 
eP,
                      LogoutFilter lF
                      , SingleSignOutFilter ssF
) {
    this.authenticationProvider = casAuthenticationProvider;
    this.authenticationEntryPoint = eP;

    this.logoutFilter = lF;
    this.singleSignOutFilter = ssF;

}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/**", "/path-1", "/path-2")
    .authenticated()
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .regexMatchers("/")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .httpBasic()
    .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
    .and()
    .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
    .and()
    .addFilterBefore(singleSignOutFilter, CasAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .addFilterBefore(logoutFilter, LogoutFilter.class);

}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
  auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
}

@Override
protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
  return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(authenticationProvider));
}

@Bean
public CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter(ServiceProperties sP) throws Exception {
  CasAuthenticationFilter filter = new CasAuthenticationFilter();
  filter.setServiceProperties(sP);
  filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
  return filter;
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler handler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    handler.setUseReferer(true);
    return handler;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using of `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` instead of `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` might help you achieve the redirection.

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
    SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler handler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    handler.setTargetUrlParameter("redirectTo");
    handler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/");
    return handler;
}
```